# Discriminant of $p(x)=x^n+a_n$

Tags: polynomials

I am trying to prove that the discriminant of $p(x)=x^n+a_n$ is given by $\Delta(p)=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}n^na_{n}^{n-1}$.

I think I can show this from the definition given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant), but the question includes a hint:

(Hint: find a formula for the discriminant in terms of $p'(\alpha_i)$ where $\alpha_i$
are the roots of $p$.)

I am not sure how to use this hint and if I need to use it, but I feel as if it would be instructive to know.

Answer (score 0):

$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}p'(\alpha_i)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j\ne i}^{}(\alpha_i-\alpha_j)=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}disc(f)$$

Here we have $p'(\alpha_i)=n\alpha_i^{n-1}=-na_n/\alpha_i$. So
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}p'(\alpha_i)=\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-na_n/\alpha_i)= n^na_n^n/a_n=n^na_n^{n-1}$$
because $\prod \alpha_i =(-1)^na_n$.